# Android/OpenglES2/examples: Why use ByteBuffer for coords?

Tags: android, opengl-es, bytebuffer

Good day my friends,

I'm new to Android and Java in general, so sorry for noob question.
I came across standard OpenGl ES examples and tried to understand this code:

```
static float wallCoords[] = {
        // in counterclockwise order:
        -0.5f,  0.6f, 0.0f,   // top left
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
        0.5f,   0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
        0.5f,   0.6f, 0.0f,   // top right
};
private final int vertexCount = wallCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 0.0f };

private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private final ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
private final short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw vertices

...

ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
        // (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
            wallCoords.length * 4);
// use the device hardware's native byte order
bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
// create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
// add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
vertexBuffer.put(wallCoords);
// set the buffer to read the first coordinate
vertexBuffer.position(0);
```

So my question is why not use FloatBuffer.wrap() method for example:

```
vertexBuffer = FloatBuffer.wrap(wallCoords);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is for performance reasons.

`FloatBuffer` doesn't have an `allocateDirect` method that allocates a [direct buffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#direct):

> **Direct vs. non-direct buffers**
>
> A byte buffer is either direct or non-direct. Given a direct byte buffer, the Java virtual machine will make a best effort to perform native I/O operations directly upon it. That is, it will attempt to avoid copying the buffer's content to (or from) an intermediate buffer before (or after) each invocation of one of the underlying operating system's native I/O operations.
>
> A direct byte buffer may be created by invoking the allocateDirect factory method of this class. The buffers returned by this method typically have somewhat higher allocation and deallocation costs than non-direct buffers.

In fact the [`FloatBuffer.wrap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/FloatBuffer.html#wrap(float[])) strongly ties the array and the buffer

> The new buffer will be backed by the given float array; that is, modifications to the buffer will cause the array to be modified and vice versa.

At the cost of possibly copying data around.

Comment: Yes, correct :) just found this explanation. This however doesn't explain that there is no comfortable API for this. Anyways, Buffer and array are tied strongly in this situation (and frankly, in Android it will always be so).